# How to parallelize downloads from the same bucket with no filtering?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a huge bucket with millions of files. I do some filtering based on database searches and I come up with a list of row ids. These row ids are the actual file names that I require from the s3 bucket.

However, downloading the files one by one is a very, very slow process. There is no predictable pattern to the file names. They are just numbers.

Is there any way to write the cp command so that the files are downloaded in parallel so that the download will happen faster?

Answer (score 0):

There are generally two ways to increase download speed.

1. Downloading first to **EC2 instance** EBS-optimized non-bur stable, in same region as the bucket, and then processing files on the instance, or downloading them as one/few bigger archives from the instance.
2. **Parallelization** which you already mentioned.

Regarding the second point, I don't have CLI command, but I generally use a simple python script. Something along these lines:

```
import boto3

from multiprocessing import Pool

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def s3_download(object_path):
    
    print(f"Downloading {object_path}")
    
    s3.download_file(object_path[0], 
                     object_path[1], 
                     f"/tmp/{object_path[1]}")    
    
    print(f"{object_path} downloaded")

object_path_list = [
    ('bucket_name', 'object_key1'),
    ('bucket_name', 'object_key2'),
    ('bucket_name', 'object_key3'),        
]

NO_OF_CORES = 4

with Pool(NO_OF_CORES) as p:
    p.map(s3_download, object_path_list)
```

Obviously, the above should be adjusted to your exact needs. Its just an example.

Comment: The files are being downloaded to an EC2 instance. I don't require them in my local computer as I processed them right then and there to generate the final file. Also I'm not well versed in python. Could you give an idea of what your script is doing? It seems to be using a multi threading library to run up NO_OF_CORS parallel downloads. But I'm not sure

Comment: @aarelovich As you described. Each process will get a chuck of the `object_path_list` to download.

Comment: @aarelovich Also, since you are using EC2 instance, to access S3 you will need appropriate instance role with S3 read-only permissions.

Comment: yes, permissions have already been set up. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

long time ago, I used JetSet to download 1000 parallel downloads: https://github.com/mondain/jets3t

but I doin't recall if it supports predefined list of files.